# How to search a string in an array of strings using Apache Spark SQL query?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an array of strings like this:

```
SELECT ARRAY('item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3') AS items
```

Result:

```
items
Type : ARRAY<STRING>
["item_1","item_2","item_3"]
```

I would like to search for an item inside of it, but if I try the regular way:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE items = 'item_1'
```

I'll get this error:

> Cannot resolve '(items.`items` = 'item_1')' due to data type mismatch
> differing types in '(items.`items` = 'item_1')' (array and
> string). line 1 pos 26

So, what can I do to search a string value inside of an array of strings using a Spark SQL query?

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_contains`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_contains) function:

```sql
SELECT * FROM items WHERE array_contains(items, 'item_1')
```